# Fastest way to convert list to dict with list values as keys, and list index as values

Tags: python

We can convert a list to dict, setting the list values as the keys, and setting the list indexes as the values thusly:

```
classes = ['car', 'bus', 'van']

reverse_classes = dict.fromkeys(classes)
for i, key in enumerate(reverse_classes):
    reverse_classes[key] = i

print(reverse_classes)
```

`{'car': 0, 'bus': 1, 'van': 2}`

**The question is:** Is this the fastest way?

### Context:

This is used to quickly get the index of the class in a `__getitem__` implementation of a custom `torch.utils.data.Dataset` while training:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

## Load all training data from https://github.com/PKU-IMRE/VERI-Wild, and set all images minus 1 per class for training, and keep the last one for testing
class VeRIWild(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, main_dir, transform, train=True, debug=False):
        self.root_dir = main_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.train = train
        self.classes = natsort.natsorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(self.root_dir, 'images')))
        self.total_imgs = []
        for car in self.classes:
            imgs = natsort.natsorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(self.root_dir, 'images', car)))
            if train:
                for im in imgs[:-1]: # keep the last image for test
                    self.total_imgs.append(os.path.join(car, im))
            else:
                self.total_imgs.append(os.path.join(car, imgs[-1]))

        self.reverse_classes = dict.fromkeys(self.classes)
        for i, key in enumerate(self.reverse_classes):
            self.reverse_classes[key] = i
            

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.total_imgs)

    ## Returns: Tuple (image, target) where target is the index of the target category.
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_loc = os.path.join(self.root_dir, 'images', self.total_imgs[idx])
        image = Image.open(img_loc).convert("RGB")
        tensor_image = self.transform(image)
        car_name = os.path.dirname(self.total_imgs[idx])
        return (tensor_image, self.reverse_classes[car_name])
```

Comment: The obvious way to do it is `{x: i for i, x in enumerate(classes)}`, which might or might not be fastest but it would certainly be worth timing it to see what you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
out = dict(zip(data, range(len(data))))
```

Simple benchmark (try it on larger dataset):

```
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import count

# classes = ['car', 'bus', 'van']
classes = set('''Est voluptatum fuga natus ea officiis eveniet facere aut. Nihil eaque quia dolor officia. Et dolorem et aut laborum impedit accusantium consequatur. Atque tempora facilis iusto. Sit neque eligendi et accusantium et. Ut veritatis in voluptatum'''.split())

def f1(data):
    reverse_classes = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(data)}
    return reverse_classes

def f2(data):
    reverse_classes = dict.fromkeys(data)
    for i, key in enumerate(reverse_classes):
        reverse_classes[key] = i
    return reverse_classes

def f3(data):
    return dict(zip(data, range(len(data))))

def f4(data):
    return dict(zip(data, count()))


t1 = timeit(lambda: f1(classes), number=1000)
t2 = timeit(lambda: f2(classes), number=1000)
t3 = timeit(lambda: f3(classes), number=1000)
t4 = timeit(lambda: f4(classes), number=1000)

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
print(t4)
```

Prints:

```
0.006092605064623058
0.007285483996383846
0.004913415992632508
0.0048480971017852426
```

---

EDIT: Added version with `itertools.count` (Thanks @HeapOverflow)

Comment: interesting to see that `zip`ping the list and the `range` is actually faster than `enumerate`...

Comment: Looks like you could easily use a much larger `number`. And `count()` seems to lead to an about 9% faster solution for me.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I added it to the tests. On my ancient computer at work (first gen i3 530) the result is -/+ same as `range()`

Comment: Seems to also only be due to the creation overhead. If I prepare the `range` before the benchmark, they're about equally fast for me as well. So in a much longer list, it probably wouldn't matter.

Comment: I confirm `dict(zip(data, count()))` is the fastest, with 40k sized data tests

Answer (score 1):

Define *fastest*?

The simplest, and probably most pythonic way, would be to use a dict-comprehension:

```py
classes = [...]
reverse_classes = {item : idx for idx, item in enumerate(classes)}
```

Note that this will keep the last item only:

```py
>>> classes = ['car', 'bus', 'van', 'car']
>>> {item: idx for idx, item in enumerate(classes)}
{'car': 3, 'bus': 1, 'van': 2}
```

Comment: Another way to write it using map: `dict(map(reversed,enumerate(classes)))`

Comment: @GáborFekete that is not going to be very *fast*...

Comment: Oh I see, yeah it's not that fast, on my machine I got 0.00786 using Andrej Kesely's timeit code.